# Column wise sum in PHP from HTML table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to sum of a column

```
<table width="240" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="94">Name</td>
        <td width="130">Current Amount</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        do {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row_Record['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_Record['current_amount']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
        }
        while ($row_Record = mysql_fetch_assoc($Record));
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Total = </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I don't know how to do this kind of sum. 
Please any one help me.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you want to sum?

Comment: do you want to sum all of the `$row_Record['current_amount']` values?

Comment: Yes. I want to sum the `$row_Record['current_amount']`

Comment: Then create a counter variable - ie. `$total = 0`. And then on each while loop add the `$row_Record['current_amount']` to that variable - `$total += $row_Record['current_amount'];` and then `echo $total;` in a last row

Comment: I did this in my answer below but for some reason I got a down vote, you can check it out

Answer (score 3):

By using **Jquery**, you can do something like that

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sum = 0
    $(".sum").each(function(){
        sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
    });
    alert(sum);
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RzDCp/)

Alternatively, you can sum all the values by using **PHP** when fetching the values.

Something like that:

```
$sum = 0;
while($read = mysqli_fetch_array()){
    $sum += $read['row'];
}
echo $sum; //total
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="240" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td width="94">Nmae</td>
        <td width="130">Current Amount</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $tmp=0;
        do {
            $tmp+=$row_Record['current_amount'];
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row_Record['name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row_Record['current_amount']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } while ($row_Record = mysql_fetch_assoc($Record)); ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">Total = <?php echo $tmp; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```